# JQM pop up issue on ipad

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page with 2 collapsible divs. User provides some search criteria in first div and below search result is appended to second collapsible div (plistviewid) dynamically:

```
<div><a href='#prid' data-role='button' data-rel='popup' data-icon='plus' data-iconpos='notext' data-theme='c' data-inline='true' data-transition='flip'>Details</a></div>
```

I am appending below popup to div 'addButton':

```
<div data-role='popup' id='prid' data-theme='c' data-overlay-theme='a' class='ui-content' data-position-to='window'>
  <p><div style='font-weight: bold;'>ISBN:</div>12345</p>
</div>
```

After search, style of div 'addButton' is changed to dispaly:block and first div 'searchLY' is collapsed. 
Clicking on 'Details' button opens up 'prid' popup and contents are displayed properly. But if I expand the first div 'searchLY' after search is complete, and then click on 'Details' button, data overlay theme changes to 'a' but the content of popup is not displayed.
This behaviour is observed only in iPad. It works fine if I test it on desktop browser.

Page:

```
<div data-role="page">
 <div data-role="content">
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c" id="searchLY">
   <label for="ISBN" class="AuthorL" id="AuthorL">ISBN:</label>
   <input id="ISBN" type="text" data-mini="true"  name="ISBN" value=""/>
   <a href="javascript:searchProducts();" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" id="searchButton">Search</a>
  </div>
 <div  id="addButton" style="display:none">
  <div data-role="content">
   <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c">
    <h3><div style="white-space:normal">Products</div></h3>
    <div data-role="content">      
       <ul id="plistviewid" data-role="listview">     
       </ul>           
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Does your script look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jmLpemu5/

Comment: @ezanker : Yes, it is almost similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.

I triggered create event for search result section (#addButton) binded to 'expand' and 'collapse' of search layout (#searchLY) which resolved the issue.

```
$("#searchLY").bind('expand', function () {
          $('#plistviewid').trigger('create');
          $('#addButton').trigger('create');
}).bind('collapse', function () {
          $('#plistviewid').trigger('create');
          $('#addButton').trigger('create');
});
```